# Bootstrap in LWC is breaking my Salesforce screen

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a Lwc that is called from a button though an aura component, inside the Account Layout, and this Lwc is calling a loadStyle bootstrap, and when I click to open my lwc, my other screens is changing, the changes just back when I reload the page.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use a [scoped Bootstrap](https://github.com/fstn/scoped-bootstrap-4) if you use `loadStyle`, or the styles will leak out to other components; anything that conflicts with [SLDS](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/). By having a scope, you'll limit the effects to just your component and its descendants. Once you used a scoped CSS, you need to include a top-level element that has the scoped class name.

Comment: thanksssssss a lot sfdcfox, i dont know how to do this but thanks, I will try searching things on the net... but thanks, i really didn't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve my problem breaking my bootstrap in two LWC differents, and importing this, to my css file of my MAIN LWC.

[image]

[image]